# How can I tell which Feature something belongs to?

Tags: 7, features

I am working on a site that has maybe 100 different Features. I am editing a block, which I assume is attached to a Feature.

Without looking through each Feature individually, how can I tell which Feature this block belongs to (or even if it is Featured at all?

Comment: in D7 i think custom blocks are not able to be "featured", that means your block is not in any feature, unless are built in a module, or is a block view.

Comment: @pinueve ah, so it I change the HTML within a block the only way to transfer that to another version of the site is copy/pasting?

Comment: yes, if is a new block, on production you have to add that new block, in both cases copy-paste blocks content  and it's settings is necesary.

Comment: is posible with this module https://www.drupal.org/project/blockexport

Answer (score 0):

You can search in your editor or your repository for your 'block_machine_name'. It must have been referenced in the respective feature.